# Joining two tables in MySQL based upon mutual likes

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Okay, so I have two MySQL tables; one is called `users` and the other is called `likes`.

**Users table**

```
id         name
-----      ------
1          Mark
2          John
3          Paul
4          Dave
5          Chris
```

**Likes table**

```
liked_by    liked  match_id
-----      ------    --------
  1          2         1
  2          1         2
  1          3         3
  2          3         4
  1          5         5
  5          1         6
```

I'm able to successfully JOIN the two tables as follows

```
SELECT users.id, likes.*
FROM users
JOIN likes
ON users.id = likes.liked
```

But, I'm not sure how to format a `WHERE` clause so that the following rows are returned.

```
name      liked_by    liked     match_id
------    -------     --------  -------- 
Mark         1           3         3
John         2           3         4
```

As you can see, I'm trying to return the rows where both Mark and John both like the same user. In this case, it's user 3, or Paul. I tried adding the following clause to the query but it clearly doesn't work.

```
WHERE (likes.liked_by = '1' OR likes.liked_by = '2')
```

Comment: I am unable to understand the `liked_by ` columns expected output ? Can you explain the bit.

Comment: Sorry. That was a typo. I fixed it now

Comment: From the output provided, I would assume, the two tables must be joined based on liked_by, i.e., ON users.id = liked_by.liked

Comment: `WHERE (likes.liked_by = '1' OR likes.liked_by = '4')` -- you aren't really putting quotes around numbers are you? They are `int` columns aren't they? So dispense with the quotes.

Comment: "_I'm trying to return the rows where both Mark and John both like the same user_" -- is that what you are _really_ trying to do? You are assuming you know the answer in your question, the way you have phrased it. Or do you _really_ want to know who likes Paul?

Comment: That's a subtle, but good point. Actually, I'm not targeting Paul in particular. I just wanna see where Mark and John's likes overlap

Comment: So the input should be 'Mark' and 'John', and the output should be overlaps?

Comment: Can you pls send or comment what is the exact output you needed?

Comment: Do you want two rows per match or one row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the liked (likees?) which have multiple rows. Otherwise it's just an inner join:

```
select *
from Likes as l inner join Users as u on u.id = l.liked_by
where liked in (
    select liked
    from Likes
    --where liked_by in (:userid1, :userid2) /* optional: specific pair of users */
    --where liked (:userid1, :userid2) /* optional: specific likee */
    group by liked
    having count(*) > 1
)
```

I hear a lot that `in` subqueries don't optimize well on MySQL. Since the grouping will guarantee a one-to-one relationship it's easy to convert that to an inner join on a derived table/inline view/nested view or whatever you guys call it.

Comment: I tried this and CodeIgniter returns a DB error reading `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.id = l.liked_by WHERE liked IN ( SELECT liked FROM li' at line 3`

Comment: I just typed too fast and basically left out the word `on`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to JOIN the `likes` table with itself to obtain **a list of pairs of users that like a particular user**. The query is fairly straight forward.

Test data:

```
CREATE TABLE users (id INT, name VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO users(id, name) VALUES (1,'Mark'), (2,'John'), (3,'Paul'), (4,'Dave'), (5,'Chris');

-- Note: I assumed that match_id is a primary key
CREATE TABLE likes (match_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, liked_by INT, liked INT);
INSERT INTO likes(liked_by, liked) VALUES (1,2), (2,1), (1,3), (2,3), (1,5), (5,1);
```

The actual query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(user1.name, ' and ', user2.name, ' like ', user3.name) AS `Readable result`
-- join the likes table with itself where two users like the same user
FROM likes AS like1
INNER JOIN likes AS like2 ON like1.liked = like2.liked AND
                             like1.match_id < like2.match_id
-- join the result with user table three times to obtain names of all users involved
INNER JOIN users AS user1 ON like1.liked_by = user1.id
INNER JOIN users AS user2 ON like2.liked_by = user2.id
INNER JOIN users AS user3 ON like1.liked = user3.id
```

Result:

```
+--------------------------+
| Readable result          |
+--------------------------+
| Mark and John like Paul  |
| John and Chris like Mark |
+--------------------------+
```